# How to make an alias for the class from internal namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, abstract-class

There is a parent class in my app:

**platform/common/baseapp.hpp:**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

namespace platform::common 
{

class BaseApp
{
    public:
        BaseApp(std::string name);
        virtual ~BaseApp() {}
        virtual int run() = 0;
    private:
        std::string m_name;
};

}
```

**platform/common/baseapp.cxx:**

```
#include "baseapp.hpp"

using namespace platform::common;

BaseApp::BaseApp(std::string name):
    m_name(std::move(name))
{
    
}
```

And an implementation for macOS:

**platform/darwin/app.hpp:**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

#include "platform/common/baseapp.hpp"

namespace platform::darwin 
{

class DarwinApp: public platform::common::BaseApp 
{
    public:
        DarwinApp(std::string name);
        int run() override;
};

}
```

**platform/darwin/app.cxx:**

```
#include "app.hpp"

using namespace platform::darwin;

DarwinApp::DarwinApp(std::string name):
    BaseApp(std::move(name))
{

}

int DarwinApp::run() {
    return 0;
}
```

Also an alias to call from `main()`:

**platform/platform.hpp:**

```
#include "flags.hpp"

namespace platform {

#if TARGET_APPLE_MACOS //It's a custom valid flag
    #include "platform/darwin/app.hpp"
    
    typedef platform::darwin::DarwinApp App;
#endif

}
```

Finally I create an instance in `main()`:

**main.cxx:**

```
#include <string>

#include "platform/platform.hpp"

using namespace platform;

int main() {
    App app(std::string("App"));
    return app.run();
}
```

However, when I try to build my app it crashes with errors:

```
build] ld: Undefined symbols:
[build]   platform::platform::darwin::DarwinApp::run(), referenced from:
[build]       _main in main.cxx.o
[build]   platform::platform::darwin::DarwinApp::DarwinApp(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>), referenced from:
[build]       _main in main.cxx.o
[build] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The problem is obviously due to namespaces, there is `platform::platform`. But I can't get how to fix it.

Comment: [Works here](https://onlinegdb.com/VVdwLKlNb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You included the header file within a namespace in platform.hpp.  You should move it out of it:

```
#include "flags.hpp"

#if TARGET_APPLE_MACOS //It's a custom valid flag
#include "platform/darwin/app.hpp"

namespace platform {
    typedef darwin::DarwinApp App;
}
#endif
```

Furthermore, being inside namespace `platform`, you don't need to repeat it in the typedef.

Comment: Thank you for help! I am a noobie in C++, I didn't know about it.

Comment: @DenisSteinman No problem.  If you come from a different language, you may have the wrong intuition for #include.  It's really a copy-paste.  Unlike "import" in other languages.